# How to update column with another subquery value in Slick?

Tags: scala, slick

I want to do something like this

```sql
UPDATE item
SET value = ( 
  SELECT max(value)
  FROM item
) 
WHERE id = 1;
```

I tried

```scala
for {
  maxValue <- Tables.Item.map(_.value).max
  x <- Tables.Item
    .filter(item => item.id === 1)
    .map(_.value).update(maxValue)
} yield x
```

but `maxValue` is a `Rep[Int]` instead of `Int`

Comment: As far as I remember you can call `result` method: `Tables.Item.map(_.value).max.result`

Comment: @Duelist max.result is a `DBIO` so I believe it will create two separate database queries instead of single SQL statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slick's `update` [doesn't support dynamic values or sub-queries](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/497). You have a couple of options for this situation.

First, you can use Plain SQL:

```
sqlu""" UPDATE item SET value = (SELECT max(value) FROM item) WHERE id = 1 """
```

Second, you could run the expression as two queries (potentially inside a transaction). This is similar to the example you have as `update` is a `DBIO`, rather than a `Query`.

I'd expect `max` to have an optional value as there might be no rows in the table:

```scala
val updateAction: DBIO[Int] = 
   Tables.Item.map(_.value).max.result.flatMap {

       case Some(maxValue) => 
        Tables.Item
          .filter(item => item.id === 1)
          .map(_.value).update(maxValue)

       case None => 
         DBIO.successful(0) // ... or whatever behaviour you want
}
```

However, perhaps your `value` field is already an option and you can use your existing for comprehension with the addition of `.result` on the end of the `maxValue` expression as mentioned by @Duelist.